# Unique ID of an embedded system running Yocto

Tags: c++, yocto

I have an embedded system running Yocto. The MAC address is not stable (it is random one that changes at every restart). The CPU ID is the same for all devices of this embedded system model.

What other options should I look for to use as unique ID of the system? I need a unique ID for licensing purposes. I should retrieve this ID from an C++ Application.

Comment: Yocto is software; you'll  need a hardware ID for such things. If you forgot to design that and got unlucky in your component choice, you might be unable to come up with a solution. There are fancy schemes based off the value of uninitialized memory (!) But those require kernel drivers

Comment: @MSalters Thanks for you reply, Actually I did not design the embedded system. It is an Intel RTF. So, I understand from your comment that only the vendor can answer my question ?

Comment: You may need to provision one for yourself in the device. A cheap way that my work okay is to generate and save a UUID to a persistent location on your device. That UUID can then be reported to a back-end service for accounting etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to ask Intel if they have space on the MCU, we usually store our MAC Address, Serial number, as well as ddr configuration there;  This can be a one time flash.

After you have confirmed the address;  You could use smbus to write the serial number into that space and retrieve it later;

This is a better way than UUID because the serial will always be there even after you have delete everything;

---

By the way, if the MAC Address is random, it is most likely because there are no MAC Address flashed into the system.

Again, ask Intel on how to flash your own MAC Address into the system.  This might eliminate the need to create another serial number;